# What is the Image size?

Tags: android

What is the image size?

Resolution 1360 * 768, Density 240
image loactation : res/drawable-hdpi/

real image size (pixel) ? 1360*768? 2040*1152?

Comment: What "image"? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Um, just to second EboMike, what are you talking about exactly?

If you have an image that is 1360 x 768 pixels, its real image size is... 1360 x 768 pixels. Density doesn't affect the image size in pixels, it affects its physical size on the display.

For example, on a 240 dpi (hdpi) Android display, a 1360 x 768 pixel image will appear as 5.67" x 3.2" (1360/240 x 768/240).

On a mdpi display (160 dpi), this 1360 x 768 pixel image will appear as 8.5" x 4.8" (1360/160 x 768/160).

Comment: Hmm, this is fishy.  Since when did density have anything to do with screen size?  An hpdi screen can be a variety of sizes.  I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: It doesn't. It has to do with pixel size and resolution. The dpi (in the case of displays, it's technically ppi - pixels per inch) is a measure of the size of the physical pixels in the display. At a density of 240 ppi, a 1" line on the screen contains 240 pixels. Naturally, 240 is just an average; many of the hdpi displays vary from this amount depending on the screen's physical size versus the resolution. (4.3" display at 854x480 is around 227 ppi). That simply means that there are 227 pixels for a 1" span. Meaning 1360/227, or 6" across, 3.38" high. Trust me, I know what I'm talking about.